# Naming convention of Layered Naviations layout file to override state.phtml Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, layout, controllers, update-handle

How is this layout file named , i mean on what basis. (Since there is no controller and router xml)

```
Magento\LayeredNavigation\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml
```

If im correct, it references the Catalog modules Controller Category path.

But from where is : "**view_type_layered**" in the layout file name coming from?

What i want to achieve:  when we click on one of the filters the file which is responsible for the results is **state.phtml** . My custom filters on click are not filtering the results.

**UPDATE**
My current overridden layout file (catalogsearch_result_index) is for view:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock class="Vendor\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" before="-" name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" before="-" name="catalogsearch.navigation.state" as="state">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_LayeredNavigation::layer/state.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

1) Should i override `state.phtml` too?

2) If so, what is the layout file name:  is it `catalog_category_view_type_layered` or `catalogsearch_result_index` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `catalog_category_view_type_layered` layout handle is added via `Magento/Catalog/Controller/Category/View.php` in the `execute()` method:

```
$hasChildren = $category->hasChildren();
if ($category->getIsAnchor()) {
    $type = $hasChildren ? 'layered' : 'layered_without_children';
} else {
    $type = $hasChildren ? 'default' : 'default_without_children';
}

if (!$hasChildren) {
    // Two levels removed from parent.  Need to add default page type.
    $parentType = strtok($type, '_');
    $page->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $parentType]);
}
$page->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $type, 'id' => $category->getId()]);
```

The `addPageLayoutHandles` method from `Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page` automatically generates the handle base on the default handle `catalog_category_view`, the key of the array `type` and the value `layered`.

Regarding your other question it totally depends on what you want to achieve:

- If you want to override the filters on the category layered page you need to use `catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml`
- If you want to override the filters on the search page you need to use `catalogsearch_result_index .xml`
- If you need to override both pages, you need both files

Comment: ok Raphael, i am overriding filters on search page,and my current layout file is correct and i get custom filters too, but, my filters dont seem to be applied on selecting one... do i need state.phtml (in my code above, state phtml doesnt seem to be called at all) or whats wrong?

Comment: @SachinS well it's hard to say without looking at the code. I reckon you should create a new question and avoid posting several questions in one post

Comment: Could you pls tell which part of my code needs to be checked, so that i can post...related to filters not getting affected

Comment: @SachinS well the part that overrides the filters

Comment: I have asked a new question here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139669/custom-filters-results-not-affectin-in-layered-navigation-magento-2 @Raphael..

Comment: Am i calling the state.phtml correctly if it has to be called, from my catalog-search_result.xml?

Comment: Any suggestion or update on the above link @Raphael?

Comment: @SachinS nope it seems super broad I'm not sure how to tackle this